# Issues with Selenium and a Single Page Application (Ember.js)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ember.js, selenium-chromedriver

I just started trying to learn to write python code today. I am trying to make a web scraper to do some stuff, but i am having trouble getting selenium to click on the specific boxes/places to get to the correct page. Because it uses Ember.js, it is a Single Page Application. This throws things off a little. I found some stuff on stackoverflow about it, but i wasnt able to get it to work. I keep getting the "NoSuchElementException" error. Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
PATH = r'C:\Users\dme03\Desktop\desktop\webdrivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://thedailyrecord.com/reader-rankings-interface/')
time.sleep(15)
mim = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//img[@src="//media.secondstreetapp.com/1973100?width=370&height=180&cropmode=Fill&anchor=Center"]/parent::div')
mim.click
```

For the XPATH, I had to select a child element and specify the parent to select the correct element. The key identifiers in the parent element kept changing, so i was unable to select just that. I believe the XPATH is correct because when I put that into the website, it showed up as the correct line.

I have also tried using the code below, as i have seen some people suggest. When using that, I get a timed out error.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//img[@src="//media.secondstreetapp.com/1973100?width=370&height=180&cropmode=Fill&anchor=Center"]/parent::div')))
```

Any help would be appreciated

NEW CODE for iFrames

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//iframe[@src="https://embed-882706.secondstreetapp.com/embed/ae709978-d6d1-499e-9f5e-136cc36eab1b/"]')))
mim = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//img[@src="//media.secondstreetapp.com/1973100?width=370&height=180&cropmode=Fill&anchor=Center"]/parent::div')))
mim.click
```

I am having issues clicking the item. To be fair, i am not sure that you are supposed to click that element to change the webpage. That is probably an issue.

Edit: nvm im just dumb that totally worked lol :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `"NoSuchElementException"` error because the desired element is inside the `iframe` .So you have to switch to iframe at first.See the below image screenshot

[image]